# Any way to "open Seq" or similar effect?

Tags: f#, refactoring

```
a 
|>Seq.map fixLine 
|>Seq.map splitCells 
|>Seq.map getName 
|>Seq.where(fun a->not<|Seq.isEmpty a) 
|>Seq.map fixName
```

Always find it annoying while keep lots of `Seq`. in lines. Suggest a good way to omit them...

For example, use `List.map` for lists, use just `map` for seq, or split them into different modules when I'm using seq and lists.

```
a
|>map fixLine
|>map splitCells
|>map getName
|>where(fun a->not<|isEmpty a)
|>map fixName
```

Looks really better.

Comment: Did you try it?  It doesn't work, but the error message pretty explicitly indicates why - the module is intentionally annotated with the `[RequireQualifiedAccess]` attribute.

Comment: If you reference [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) your code will work. You just will need to write `filter` instead of `where`. It will also work the same way with arrays and lists, depending on the type of `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also just define aliases for the functions you want:

```
let map = Seq.map
let where = Seq.filter
```

Or you could make it even more terse by defining your own operators:

```
let (|!>) s f = Seq.map f s
let (|*>) s f = Seq.filter f s

a
|!> fixLine
|!> splitCells
|!> getName
|*> (fun a->not<|isEmpty a)
|!> fixName
```

But at this point, your code becomes way too cryptic - i.e. someone looking at the code will have a hard time understanding what's going on.

And finally, you could make the original code look a bit better by noticing that a composition of `map`s is a `map` of composition:

```
a
|> Seq.map (fixLine >> splitCells >> getName)
|> Seq.filter (not << isEmpty)
|> Seq.map fixName
```

This is the solution that I personally would prefer.

---

In general, my personal experience shows that, despite the first impulse to "fix" the repetitiveness by making the repetitive parts themselves smaller, there is *usually* a better solution that would make your code not only look better, but better factored as well.

Comment: Wow, I got the way to use "`>>`" operator, thank you!

Comment: If any of the two answers helped you, would you care to "accept" one of them?

Comment: I see, I suggest it's not the final answer, but it's helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an easy way to avoid repeating the `Seq` - this is just one place where F# makes things a bit more explicit (so that you know what's going on).

But you can use the [F# Core Fluent library](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Core.Fluent/) which gives you a more C#-like syntax with `.`:

```
a.map(fixLine).map(splitCells).map(getName).filter(isEmpty >> not).map(fixName)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the timely answer!